# NHibernate Envers - HashedSet<T> throws NotImplementedException

Tags: configuration, nhibernate-envers

When I am configuring Envers with my NHibernate configuration, some of my models have collections mapped as `HashedSet<>` and when I am calling `configuration.IntegrateWithEnvers(auditConfiguration);`

I get the exception telling me that I need to define a custom `ICustomCollectionMapperFactory`.

Where do I need to define that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange. I assume you are using nh envers 1.x and nh core 3.x? If so, (iesi) hashedset<> should work just fine. What's the error message you get?

Anyhow - if you need to implement your own collectionmapperfactory (which you shouldnt need to, something else is fishy), you can have a look here...
https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers.setfornet4
...this example is used to be able to use (bcl) hashset<> as set implementation.

If you use nh envers 2.0 (and nh 4), why don't you use (bcl) hashset<> instead?